# Control python imports to reduce size and overhead

Tags: python, optimization, import, size

I have created a number of personal libraries to help with my daily coding. Best practice is to put imports at the beginning of python programs. But say I import my library, or even just a function or class from the library. All of the modules are imported (even if those modules are used in other unused classes or functions). I assume this increases the overhead of the program?

One example. I have a library called pytools which looks something like this

```
import difflib

def foo():
    # uses difflib.SequenceMatcher

def bar():
    # benign function ie
    print "Hello!"
    return True

class foobar:
    def __init__():
        print "New foobar"
    def ret_true():
        return True
```

The function foo uses difflib. Now say I am writing a new program that needs to use bar and foobar. I could either write

```
import pytools
...
item = pytools.foobar()
vals = pytools.bar()
```

or I could do

```
from pytools import foobar, bar
...
item = foobar()
vals = bar()
```

Does either choice reduce overhead or preclude the import of foo and its dependencies on difflib? What if the import to difflib was inside of the foo function?

The problem I am running into is when converting simple programs into executables that only use one or two classes or functions from my libraries, The executable ends up being 50 mb or so.

I have read through py2exe's optimizing size page and can optimize using some of its suggestions.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/OptimizingSize

I guess I am really asking for best practice here. Is there some way to preclude the import of libraries whose dependencies are in unused functions or classes? I've watched import statements execute using a debugger and it appears that python only "picks up" the line with "def somefunction" before moving on. Is the rest of the import not completed until the function/class is used? This would mean putting high volume imports at the beginning of a function or class could reduce overhead for the rest of the library.

Comment: This is actually a question about the converter from Python code to binary files.  Which converter are you using?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that? I am using python 2.6 if that helps

Comment: You are saying "…converting simple programs into executables…".  You will need some program to do this conversion.  This program will decide which modules to include.

Comment: I see. I am using py2exe. It has optimizer that allow me to "exclude" certain libraries when I create the executable. I was wondering if one could dynamically import things based on what the calling program is asking for. Specifically if a from X import Y statement skips the library and just imports the function and searches the import list for dependencies as it needs them

Comment: I never used py2exe (I'm not on Windows), so I really don't know how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to effectively reduce your dependencies is to split your tool box into smaller modules, and to only import the modules you need.

Putting imports at the beginning of unused functions will prevent loading these modules at run-time, but is discouraged because it hides the dependecies.  Moreover, your Python-to-executable converter will likely need to include these modules anyway, since Python's dynamic nature makes it impossible to statically determine which functions are actually called.

Comment: is there any way to declare in the program (for the interpreter) which functions or classes will be called (even at run time). My initial interpretation for using from X import Y was to tell the interpreter that that specific function or method was the only one I needed.

Comment: @PaulSeeb: The only way to declare this is to write small modules and only include the modules you need.

Comment: @PaulSeeb: What exactly is "this" in your last question?

Comment: In the example above, this would be pytools. Should the contents of that file be broken into smaller files to produce a package? Or are they all imported anyway using either a from x import y statement or a import x statement? Is there a reason python doesn't just declare the namespace and only fully import it if it is used?

Comment: @PaulSeeb: You can use a package if you want.  The statement `import package` does only import `package/__init__.py` and anything that is imported by it, so you have complete control over the depndencies.

Comment: @Sven_Marnach And that control is not true of importing items from a module? Why the difference?

Comment: @PaulSeeb: Packages and modules are different things, so they behave differently.  The granularity of Python imports is modules, not packages.  Why?  Guido just did it this way.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that I accepted this answer based on breaking appart a tool box into smaller modules (I used packages with great sucess). Thanks for talking me through that one